# How can we remove the current date from gradle generated .html and .xml file while running JMeter script from build.gradle file?

Tags: gradle, jmeter, build.gradle

I am running my JMeter script from build.gradle file. After executing it is generating the html and xml report files with the script name. My problem is that current date is also present with the script name. Please tell me how to remove the current date from output files.

Gradle- gradle-2.4 version and HTML Report Publisher plugin in Jenkins

Comment: Are you using the kulya gradle jmeter plugin? Why do you want to remove the current date?

Comment: @RaGe- I want to use the current report in Jenkins, but gradle creating a new report every time i run it.

Comment: Then this is an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can use wildcards in Jenkins. What jenkins plugin are you using? Please edit your question to include information about what gradle plugin and what jenkins plugin you are using.

Comment: @RaGe- using gradle-2.4 version and HTML Report Publisher plugin in Jenkins

Comment: Does not look like HTML publisher supports wildcards. My answer below is likely the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using com.github.kulya/jmeter-gradle-plugin ?

The date is tacked on to testplan name while generating results, which is then used while generating reports. The intention I believe is so that the results are not overwritten each time you run a test. [The way it is currently implemented](https://github.com/kulya/jmeter-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/kulya/gradle/plugins/jmeter/JmeterRunTask.java#L199), it isn't configurable.

If you have only one set of result and report per jmx file, You should be able to define a new task though to strip out the date/timestamp from the results and report files.

```
task stripDateFromReport() {
 new File("build/jmeter-report").eachFileMatch(~/.*.[xml|html]/){ file ->
    def m = file.getName() =~ /^(.*?)-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{4}(.*?)$/
    file.renameTo(new File(file.getParentFile().getCanonicalPath()+ File.separator + m[0][1] + m[0][2]))
  }
}
```

Note: If you have more than one report with just a different timestamp, this will obviously fail because once the dates are removed the filenames are not unique anymore.

Comment: @RaGe- Should I have to configure this code in build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes, you can add this to build.gradle. You'll have to call the task as `gradle stripDateFromReport` after executing jmeter test, before invoking your HTMLPublisher.